Should I use "thermal relief" or "solid"?
I want to create a ground plane for my circuit in KiCad:

I chose Add Filled Zone and B.Cu (back copper layer). Now, in pad connections, I can choose "Thermal relief" or "Solid".
Which one should I choose?
By the way, should I also select F.Cu? I'm not very sure what difference it makes. I just want a ground plane to make my circuit more stable.

I would recommend to connect the bottom plane to GND and the top plane to 3V3, since these are the power connections you are using. Thermal reliefs are often better to solder than solid connections.
Additional thoughts:

How do you intend to mount the pcb? I would suggest some mounting holes in the corners.
Your power traces are really thin, what speaks against making them bigger? I would choose 1mm or higher, since they carry all the current of your board.
Does the ESP32 Board need a decoupling capacitor? I would place at least one 100nF and one 1µF cpacitor near the power pins. I would recommend 0805 X7R ceramic capacitors with 10 Volts or more.


Thanks! I'll make the traces 1mm (only the power traces?). And yes, I'll add the mounting holes. I've tested without capacitors, with capacitors, and with capacitors and a resistor. They all give me the same load cell readings. https://ibb.co/2nVcPV3

@wyc i would make all traces 1mm, if they aren't any high speed clock lines

@wyc maybe add an led with a resistor between 3V3 and GND to show that the device is on? (Only if you have enough space)

Ah, the ESP32-C3 SuperMini has a onboard LED, I'm using that one. I use it to tell what the MCU is doing.  Thanks for the suggestion! By the way, do you think I should add the ground plane to B.Cu or B.Cu and F.Cu?

@wyc GND plane to B.Cu, Power plane to F.Cu. To clarify: Bottom = B.Cu, Top = F.Cu, Layer 1 in between In1.Cu and so on

For connecting to pads which will be soldered, you should generally use the thermal relief option. This prevents the copper pour from sinking away all of the heat from the iron and preventing a good solder joint. For non-solderable pads (i.e. vias) you should use the solid connection because you don't have to worry about heating the pad.
In regards to F.Cu (front copper), are you putting a ground pour on the front as well? If so, go ahead and select it. However, I would generally use a separate area for the front and the back, so that I can edit them independently should I ever need to.
Disclaimer: I am not very experienced with KiCAD, so I am trying to keep this response as general as possible so as to remain platform-agnostic.

Thanks for the answer. I just want a ground plane so that my circuit is more stable. I'm not sure if I need a ground pour on the front as well, and I'm not very sure what it means to have a ground plane in B.Cu and F.Cu as opposed to just B.Cu. Maybe I should just stick to B.Cu to be on the safe side?

@wyc Generally, for 2-layer boards, a ground plane goes on one side and the components, traces, and a power pour go on the top layer. It is best to run the supply through a pour rather than through traces

For pads that will be soldered with an iron, that is. For pads that will be reflow soldered, thermal reliefs don't usually make a difference, as the entire PCB is heated regardless.

Sorry, so this means... I should just use B.Cu for the ground plane?

@wyc Yes, in your case I would put a ground pour on B.Cu and a 3.3V pour on F.Cu

Thanks, so in what layer should I put my traces?

@wyc The traces should be on the top layer (F.Cu) along with the 3.3V pour. Bottom layer (B.Cu) should be a solid ground pour.
